# Build table from angular form data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

So I am trying to build a table that takes the form data entered and is stored on the client and pushes each input property into a group to create an object. From there, the table is build using ng-repeat. Code started is below, but nothing is happening. Can anyone assist?

```
                <form class="addClaim" ng-submit="submitClaim(claimInfo)">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="beneSelect">Select your benefit</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="beneSelect" >
                            <option ng-repeat="descr in claim.claimBenes" data-ng-model="claimInfo.providerName">{{ descr.descr }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="start">Date of Service</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start" placeholder="--/--/----" data-ng-model="claimInfo.fromDate" style="width: 240px;">
                            <span>To</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end" placeholder="--/--/---- (optional)" data-ng-model="claimInfo.toDate" style="width: 240px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="providerName">Provider Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="providerName" data-ng-model="claimInfo.provider">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="forWhom">For Whom</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="forWhom" data-ng-model="claimInfo.who">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-show="claimInfo.benefCode == 'HCFSA'">
                        <label for="age">Age</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" data-ng-model="claimInfo.who">
                    </div>                    

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="claimAmount">Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claimAmount" data-ng-model="claimInfo.amount">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="claimComment">Comments</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="claimComment" data-ng-model="claimInfo.comments"></textarea>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label"></label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveClaim()" value="add claim" style="float: right;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

The table:

```
<div class="claimedTable" style="background-color: #ffffff; color: black;">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>service date</th>
                <th>provider</th>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th>edit</th>
                <th>delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in claimSubmit">
                <td>{{ claimInfo.fromDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ claimInfo.provider }}</td>
                <td>{{ claimInfo.amount }}</td>
                <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>            
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
$scope.claim = [];

claimsService.getClaim().then(function (results) {

    $scope.claim = results.data;

});

// submit all claim objects entered
$scope.claimsSubmit = [];

$scope.claimInfo = {
    id: "",
    benefitId: "",
    isSecIns: "",
    isNoResId: "",
    expenseTypeId: "",
    fromDate: "",
    toDate: "",
    provider: "",
    who: "",
    depId: "",
    age: "",   
    amount: "",
    comments: "",
    isOffset: ""
};

$scope.saveClaim = function() {
    $scope.claimsSubmit.push($scope.claimInfo);
    //clears scope so form is empty
    $scope.claimInfo = {};
}
```

When I enter data into the fields and click submit, nothing ever leaves nor does it post to the table. The reason I want as an object versus an array is because the table may have multiple line items depending on how many times the form is field out and submitted.

Seems somewhere simple I am going wrong, but cannot figure where. Any help please?

Thanks much.

Comment: Did you try with: **<td>{{ item.fromDate }}</td>** ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that route with no luck.

Comment: check your typo mismatches ...works with modifications using `ng-submit` here http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMOqLs5rPx9GFwrmUDtj?p=preview

Comment: Yes, claimsSubmit or claimSubmit?

Comment: @charlietfl - So based on that plunker, I am trying to figure how I can keep this persisted if the browser accidentally refreshes. What I want to do is save each one ass an object like you have shown, but then in my html, I will add a button with a function that will then push the data as an array of objects to an API. Is that possible?

Comment: send on submit and push to array once you have save confirmation from server

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues in your code. Here it is cleaned up a bit...

HTML

```
<form class="addClaim"> // ng-submit not needed in form tag
```

ng-repeat bindings should be item. not claimsSubmit.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in claimsSubmit">
  <td>{{ item.fromDate }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.provider }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.amount }}</td>
  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></td>
  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>            
</tr>
```

Controller

```
$scope.claim = []; // This can be removed.

claimsService.getClaim().then(function (results) {
    $scope.claim = results.data;
});

// submit all claim objects entered
$scope.claimsSubmit = [];
$scope.claimInfo = {}; // This just needs to create an object.

$scope.saveClaim = function() {
    $scope.claimsSubmit.push($scope.claimInfo);
    //clears scope so form is empty
    $scope.claimInfo = {};
}
```

This should be enough to get the form populating the table for you. There is obviously form data missing from the table but it will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: how I can keep this persisted if the browser accidentally refreshes. What I want to do is save each one ass an object like you have shown, but then in my html, I will add a button with a function that will then push the data as an array of objects to an API. Is that possible?

Comment: You can persist the data in the browser localStorage. Just create a keyup or blur event listener that writes the table object as a JSON string to the storage. When the page loads, you can check for its existence and populate the table object with the data found there if it does exist. On form submit, you can delete the storage value.

Comment: i disagree about using button event instead of `ng-submit`.... lets you catch keyboard submittal which is more user friendly

Comment: @charlietfl Agreed. I didn't want to change too much of this code though. Just wanted to get it up and running for this question. There are quite a few things that should be updated in it.

Comment: @charlietfl - I think the ng-submit based on what I know is a decent way. Working through that plunker though, am having problems capturing the array of objects and then pushing to API. Any chance you can edit to explain? Seems I would have to name each object or set something to differentiate them. Appreciate it!

Comment: `$http.post( url, $scope.claimInfo)` should do it...use callback to push data to array ... oh and use `angular.copy` so you don't keep pushing the same object

Comment: Wouldn't this require an additional <form> tag if I put this in the div that resides with the table info rather than with the div that contains the form?

Comment: So having this blows it up: $scope.saveallClaims = function() {
  $http.post( http://rainier.8013//api/ppt/claims/benefits, $scope.claimInfo)
} think I am lost here....

Comment: @charlietfl - any ideas on why this would blow up?: $scope.saveallClaims = function() { $http.post( rainier.8013//api/ppt/claims/benefits, $scope.claimInfo) }